# Visual Studio 2010 Debugging issue

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2010

I have a problem with debugging my Silverlight 4 (hosted in ASP.NET MVC2) in Visual Studio 2010. It was working fine until I tried remote debugging. After a lot of hassle I managed to configure remote debugging but it worked only occasionally. So I created a new app and copied my classes one by one, but now I see I cannot debug not only remotely but also "locally" in development server. Breakpoints in Silverlight code says "The breakpoint will not currently be hit. No symbols have been loaded for this document." Strangely enough, if I run my app it will show my previous code results. (It may be relevant, before this problem I noticed that my app doesn't update immediately when I publish to remote web server. So I did the following for all projects in the solution:

```
//In AssemblyInfo.cs in Properties folder
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.*")]
[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("1.0.*")]
```

I'm adviced that it will automatically generate version numbers so, when I publish to remote server it will immediately take into effect, which seems working well.)

However, if I change development server's port number, in the properties page of my ASP.NET MVC app, then I'm able to debug locally (about remote debugging I just gave up). But, it didn't last long; after some updates in my code the problem suddenly reoccurs. I guess development server deploys my app somewhere in a folder per port number, but where? May be, if I delete that folder, will the problem be solved? Can somebody advice me what to do?

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be bug in Visual Studio 2010; see:

[silverlight 4, dynamically loading xap modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3673718/silverlight-4-dynamically-loading-xap-modules)